# Name variation on credit report in the UK, reason for concern?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-report, mistakes

I have three surnames, so my full legal name is generally written here (HMRC, DVLA, passport, pay slips) as:
**Forename Surname#1 Surname#2 Surname#3**

I pulled my credit report and my current account name is listed as follows:
**Forename Surname#1 Surname#3**, so Surname#2 is missing.

I contacted the bank that manages my current account, but they only have my full legal name registered in their system. This information is corroborated by the bank statements that show my full legal name. The bank states it is impossible they sent only two of my three surnames.

Is this reason for concern? Should I insist with the credit report agency to get it corrected?
In their automated system, I am not allowed to raise a dispute concerning my name, because it was reported as such by the bank.